# General C++ Array of Arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a general class and had to create a function that should get this parameters:

- a vector *arrays* of arrays of any type,
- a vector *size* of the type size_t which describe the sizes of *arrays*.

I came to:

```
function(std::vector< size_t > size, std::vector< std::vector< void > > arrays)
```

but it doesn't seem to work to set a vector of int as an entry of the array.

Does someone have an idea how to get this working?

Thanks in advance,
 - fodinabor

Comment: Please show the code calling the function; does it compile? What exactly is not working?

Comment: The function needs to be tamplated. I'm not even sure `std::vector<void>` will compile. The sizes are superfluous since each vector holds its own size internally.

Comment: Make a function template, not a function.

Comment: on Linux it built with void I think :), and it seems to work, thank you ;-) I acutally never had used a template function :O
size of an array would be sizeof(arrays[i])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class Array>
void function(std::vector<Array> arrays, std::vector<size_t> size) {
    //use arrays[2][size[2] -1] to access the last element of the 3rd array, for example
}
```

and then, to call it:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    /* example with int* as the array type, but could be a vector or an array of double, char, ... */
    int array1[4] = {1,2,3,9};
    int array2[5] = {1,2,3,9,6};
    int array3[3] = {1,2,-2};

    std::vector<int*> arrays; 
    arrays.push_back(array1);
    arrays.push_back(array2);
    arrays.push_back(array3);
    std::vector<size_t> size;
    size.push_back(4);
    size.push_back(5);
    size.push_back(3);

    function(arrays, size);
}
```

Comment: So I use as my function call (constructor):
`PolyCL(OCLSource,name,arrays,size);`
the declaration: `template <class Array>
PolyCL::PolyCL(String kernelSource, String kernelName, std::vector< Array > arrays, std::vector<size_t> size)`
OCL and name are Strings, arrays is defined by: ` std::vector<float*> arrays(3);
`
size as: ` std::vector<size_t> size;`

Comment: but when I link I get:
`error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall Polycode::PolyCL::PolyCL<float>(class Polycode::String,class Polycode::String,class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> >,class std::vector<unsigned int,class std::allocator<unsigned int> >)" (??$?0M@PolyCL@Polycode@@QAE@VString@1@0V?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@V?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@4@@Z)".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your whole code, and maybe ask a new question. But the problem seems to be that your function isn't defined, or if it's a template it needs to be defined in the header (the code needs to be in the header, not the cpp).